# Flipboard first screen functionality

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

Please tell me the Flipboard first screen animation functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are looking for is knwn as **Ken Burns Effect** or ***Panning***

here is the code to apply it..

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:7];

        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
        CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.00);
        CGAffineTransform moveLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.9,0.9);
        CGAffineTransform combo1 = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotate, moveLeft);

        CGAffineTransform zoomOut = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1,1.1);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(zoomOut, combo1);
        background.transform = transform;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i have 4 images it works fine with for first image. but not give same effect on other images.

Comment: Shrey give me any idea for how 4 images(Array) show in UIView.some thing wrong in my logic animation work only for first image. please help me.

Comment: i'll tell you what i did..but you can think of more optimized way..

I used 1 ImageView with 4 UIImages and to change the image after panning, i crossfade it, and then start the panning of the second image. But its not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/03/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-3-splash-screen/) may help you